# Getting KeyError: 0 when executing the Python script

Tags: python, json, parsing

The problem is when I am running the script I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test1.py", line 16, in
>   
>       output.writerow(data[0].keys()) KeyError: 0

Following is the python code:

```
import csv, json, sys

if sys.argv[1] is not None and sys.argv[2] is not None:
    fileInput = sys.argv[1]
    fileOutput = sys.argv[2]

    inputFile = open(fileInput)
    outputFile = open(fileOutput, 'w')
    data = json.load(inputFile)
    inputFile.close()

    output = csv.writer(outputFile)

    output.writerow(data[0].keys())

    for row in data:
        output.writerow(row.values())
```

Formatted JSON data :

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T11:20:37",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 1,
            "raw_message": "A sinking pound, resignations by the bucketful railroading through a so-called agreement nobody wants. For the good of the country Mrs. May 'go and go now'.",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T11:20:37",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2",
                "url": "",
                "id": "250728493",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T10:40:52",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
                "name": "baggiebuoy"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 1,
            "id": "4196155749",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>A sinking pound, resignations by the bucketful railroading through a so-called agreement nobody wants. For the good of the country Mrs. May 'go and go now'.</p>",
            "isEdited": true,
            "isApproved": true
        },
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:37:59",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "raw_message": "This could be heaven, or this could be hell.",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:37:59",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b",
                "url": "",
                "id": "250739494",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T13:01:02",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": false,
                "name": "Mordecai"
            },
            "parent": 4196013534,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 0,
            "id": "4196048572",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>This could be heaven, or this could be hell.</p>",
            "isEdited": false,
            "isApproved": true
        },
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:36:50",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "raw_message": "The crappest of crap deals.\nWill never get through Parliament.\n\nYou are the weakest link May, goodbye.",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:36:50",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b",
                "url": "",
                "id": "250739494",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-29e1c59be16c852670e3be302e8c303b.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T13:01:02",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": false,
                "name": "Mordecai"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 0,
            "id": "4196044068",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>The crappest of crap deals.<br>Will never get through Parliament.</p><p>You are the weakest link May, goodbye.</p>",
            "isEdited": false,
            "isApproved": true
        },
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:28:13",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "raw_message": "We are all just prisoners here of our own device. \ud83d\ude01",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:28:13",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140",
                "url": "",
                "id": "274657487",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-12-20T16:45:10",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
                "name": "chaffwolf"
            },
            "parent": 4195981074,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 0,
            "id": "4196013534",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>We are all just prisoners here of our own device. \ud83d\ude01</p>",
            "isEdited": false,
            "isApproved": true
        },
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:27:03",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "raw_message": "Should be no deal end off.\nNobody could possibly be the winner so it's simple leave and that's it .\nTheir will always be wannabes who think they can do better in it for only their own powers not for the general country or the people of it .,",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:27:03",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c",
                "url": "",
                "id": "251694793",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-90ecce8d5dad4396f681182cb470872c.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-05-12T20:20:43",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
                "name": "wanderer in eire"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 0,
            "id": "4196012501",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>Should be no deal end off.<br>Nobody could possibly be the winner so it's simple leave and that's it .<br>Their will always be wannabes who think they can do better in it for only their own powers not for the general country or the people of it .,</p>",
            "isEdited": false,
            "isApproved": true
        },
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T10:26:42",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "raw_message": "Damned if she does, damned if she doesn't. All for a cause she does not believe in.\nShe will go down in history whatever happens. \nThe question is: who better to lead the country at such an important juncture??\nAnswers on a postcard!",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T10:26:42",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140",
                "url": "",
                "id": "274657487",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-42ba513c42a0fd6558aa44b1de658140.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-12-20T16:45:10",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
                "name": "chaffwolf"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 0,
            "id": "4196012237",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>Damned if she does, damned if she doesn't. All for a cause she does not believe in.<br>She will go down in history whatever happens. <br>The question is: who better to lead the country at such an important juncture??<br>Answers on a postcard!</p>",
            "isEdited": false,
            "isApproved": true
        },
        {
            "thread": "7046384220",
            "numReports": 0,
            "editableUntil": "2018-11-22T09:50:32",
            "sb": false,
            "media": [],
            "moderationLabels": [],
            "isSpam": false,
            "isHighlighted": false,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "points": 0,
            "raw_message": "Theresa May is using The Eagles Hotel California lyrics as the inspiration for her Brexit plan.\n\nYou can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.",
            "forum": "expressandstar",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-15T09:50:32",
            "canVote": false,
            "author": {
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada",
                "url": "",
                "id": "250727584",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "avatar": {
                    "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada.jpg",
                    "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png",
                    "small": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar32.png"
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "permalink": "https://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/mnaid-e82a88d937e60267fd2c866b01131ada.jpg",
                        "cache": "//a.disquscdn.com/1541535443/images/noavatar92.png"
                    },
                    "isCustom": false
                },
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T10:27:23",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": false,
                "name": "Olly the cat"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "likes": 0,
            "id": "4195981074",
            "isDeletedByAuthor": false,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "message": "<p>Theresa May is using The Eagles Hotel California lyrics as the inspiration for her Brexit plan.</p><p>You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.</p>",
            "isEdited": false,
            "isApproved": true
        }
    ],
    "code": 0,
    "cursor": {
        "more": false,
        "total": null,
        "prev": null,
        "hasNext": false,
        "next": "1542275432008325:1:0",
        "id": "1542275432008325:1:0",
        "hasPrev": false
    }
}
```

My main project is taking data from the JSON file and making a relational database with the data.

Comment: what is `data`? what is `data[0]`? The error message seems pretty clear frankly, check your code.

Comment: Try `output.writerow(data['response'][0].keys())`

Comment: @FilipMłynarski I am getting the following error if i do that ````Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 20, in <module>
    output.writerow(row.values())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' ````

Comment: @ParitoshSingh data is storing the json data in the text file. I am using the data[0] to access the keys to form the columns.

Comment: try to run it separately and see if it actually works like you think it does. (ps. data is a dictionary after you load it in. does it have a `0` key?)

Comment: If your goal is to make a relational database, it is possible that converting to a flat CSV is not the ideal first step.

Comment: @rici which process would you suggest I take to achieve the end goal

Comment: I'd suggest you start by creating the necessary database tables, if they haven't yet been created. You might have to design them, depending on the requirements of your assignment, or you might have been given them. Once you have the database structure in place, figure out how to map each json record to the database, which likely involves adding to various tables. Then read up on the Python interface to whatever database you're using, paying particular attention to prepared statements. Using that API, connect to the database and convert each json record into the necessary INSERT commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top-level object in that JSON data is a dictionary. But you are trying to index it as though it were a list. (`data[0]`). Since 0 is not a key of the dictionary, trying to use it as a key results in a `KeyError`.

If you want the keys of the top-kevel object, use `data.keys()`.